# A list of all questions ever featured in meta

Tags: discussion, meta, featured-questions

Can we somehow see a list of all the questions that were ever [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) in meta at some point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1195236) to find the still visible questions that once had the featured tag.

We basically look at the PostHistory table and look for events where tags are added/edited.

```sql
select postid as [Post Link]
     , count(*) [# of times]
from posthistory
where posthistorytypeid in (3,6,9)
and text like '%<featured>%'
group by postid
order by min(creationdate)desc
```

when run today this is your result:

[image]

There are no deleted questions that still have the featured tag but I can't rule out some deleted question might have had them. If you want those, you would need a CM to run the query on the internal SEDE instance.

Comment: Kinda disappointed. I thought it would take you less time to answer this. Do try to keep up.

Comment: OK, I was trying to look into the edits directly to try and find the tag there. But for some reason the RevisionGUID from `PostHistory` doesn't link to RevisionGUID in `SuggestedEdits`? I'm quite new to SEDE, so maybe I'm missing something but I thought edits were supposed to be in the `SuggestedEdits` table (even though nobody votes on them). Perhaps my approach was overly formal but it was to familiarise myself with the db structure - I wanted to join `PostHistory` to the edits and check for an edit that introduced the `featured` tag.

Comment: @VLAZ not all edits are suggested-edits. Suggested edits only hold those that are by <2k users and mod edits never go through the queue anyway as their edits are binding. PostHistory is the only table you need (and the text column will hold what was changed for edits)

Comment: @yivi I only saw it after your edit ... :/

Comment: @rene thanks. So `SuggestedEdits` really is (as the name states) for suggested edits? I just thought that was...odd. I expected an edit to make a "suggested" edit and auto-approve it or something. So, do 2k+ edits go straight into `PostHistory`? It just seems slightly error-prone to look at just the Comment column. Although I guess if you change the text in the post *and* edits you get two entries in the table. Right now I'm mostly guessing and trying to verify my ideas of how it *probably* works by checking against a real example.

Comment: Yes, they go straight into posthistory. I have an answer on revisions on MSE https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/297037/158100 @VLAZ

Comment: @rene OK, thank you that clears up things a lot. The RevisionGUID misled me, I suppose. I thought it was a foreign link where it's actually referring to the same table, grouping entries together.